# How to get python to read all images in a directory one by one

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, io

My experience with python is very limited so I don't fully understand what the code does in this instance. This is part of the code for poets lab from the tensorflow framework.

```
import os, sys

import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

image = Image.open(image_path)      
image_array = image.convert('RGB')

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
               in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
    score = predictions[0][node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))


filename = "results.txt"    
with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
    f.write('\n**%s**\n' % (image_path))
    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
    f.write('%s (score = %.5f)\n' % (human_string, score))
```

I want the above code to read in a directory instead of a single image and then process them all and output the scores to the results.txt file.
Currently I can call this like so:

```
python this_file.py /root/images/1.jpg
```

How would I get this code to take the following input and processes it

```
python this_file.py /root/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use os.listdir to list all files in the directory. Qualify it with a filter as well. Join the resulting files to their directory. Read them from the list with a for loop.

> > > python this_file.py /root/images/

```
image_path = sys.argv[1]
image_paths = [os.path.join(image_path,img) for img in  os.listdir(image_path) if '.jpg' in img]
```

I also recommend re-examining your training function and strategy. It is also good practice to abstract your entire network with tf variable placeholders as far as you can. In addition it would be much more efficient to implement batching, as well as possibly convert your dataset to tf records.